# PHP/JSON - Remove every occurence of certain character before another character

Tags: php, json, character

My JSON is encoding peculiarly, so I need to remove every quote before a right-opening bracket. (e.g. every " before a {)  Is it possible to do this in PHP, and if so, how?

"{ I would want to remove every occurrence of the quote before the bracket.

JSON here: http://devticker.pw/json-data.php

Code here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$data[] = '{"c": [{ "v": ' . $row['Timestamp'] . '"},{"v":' . $row['USD'] . '} ]}';
}

$str = json_encode(array("rows"=>$data));

$str = substr($str, 1);

$str = str_replace("\"{", "{", $str);

$str = '{"cols":[{"type":"string"},{"type":"number"}],' . $str;

$str = stripslashes($str);

echo $str;
```

Comment: You're manipulating raw JSON instead of elements in an array because...?

Comment: I'm turning data from a MySQL database into an array (while loop), then json-encoding them.  I don't think I can do it from the array elements themselves.

Comment: Ok. Looks like you have a JSON encoded array that has elements saved as JSON encoded, instead of a multi-dimensional array stored as one JSON string. The answers given hopefully fix your code, but if possible you should encode it properly in the first place. Can you show the code that generates it?

Comment: Post the code that generates the json and maybe we can help you fix it at the source.

Comment: I edited the original question, the code is on there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are generating part of the JSON manually and then encoding that string with `json_encode`, which is escaping the quotes that should not be escaped. This is wrong. Using `str_replace` to remove the escaping is a workarround, not the correct way to generate your JSON.

If you generate your JSON using only `json_encode` it works well. Something like this should work:

```
// your columns
$cols = array();
$cols[0] = array('type' => 'string');
$cols[1] = array('type' => 'number');

// your rows
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $r = new stdClass();
    $r->c = array();

    $r->c[0] = array('v' => $row['Timestamp']);
    $r->c[1] = array('v' => $row['USD']);

    $rows[] = $r;
}

// the final result
$result = array(
    'cols' => $cols,
    'rows' => $rows
);

// don't forget this
header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $data[] = array("c" => array(array( "v" => $row['Timestamp']), array("v" => $row['USD'] ))));
}

$rows = array("rows"=>$data));

$cols = array("cols" => array(array("type"=>"string"),array("type"=>"number")),$row);

$str = json_encode($cols);

echo $str;
```

Comment: The str_replace worked for me, but thanks anyway for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

Really can't understand why you need to do this (and why you are manupulating raw JSON string), but you can simply use the string-replacement function of php, [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$your_json_string = str_replace("\"{", "{", $your_json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = str_replace('"{','{',$json)
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of PHP are you using?

If 5.3 or greater than you can use this:

```
return json_encode($var, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
```

Frameworks like drupal have handled this stuff - you could probably rip some code from here to roll your own json_encode function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_json_encode/7