# PHP: How to get rid of strange characters like "\u00a0"?

Tags: php, special-characters, hidden-characters, non-breaking-characters

I got a messy bunch of JSON data to import into my database (for further purposes). When i checked them out (opened in a Text Editor), they contain so many weird (gibberish) characters like:

- \u00a0

For example, `data.json`:

```
[{"title":"hello world!","html_body":"<p>Hello\u00a0 from the\u00a0  other side.\u00a0 <\/p>"}]
```

And then, obviously, below code simply WON'T work:

```
$clean = str_replace("\u00a0", "", $string);
```

Despite whatever those character are for, **how can i get rid of them** anyway please?

Comment: U+00A0 is a no-break space, not gibberish. It *may* be meaningful and intentional. (Though in this case it may not be.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20734771/php-json-remove-every-occurence-of-certain-character-before-another-character

Comment: @deceze did you recognise this immediately, or did you research what this character (group) was?

Comment: @Martin OS X's handy character viewer tool… 

Comment: * shakes fist * damn Apple, being better!! `:-D`

Comment: Are there many other characters in this JSON, or just this one, that needs removal?

Comment: @axiac strange, that deceze claims its a non-breaking space, it can't be both....

Comment: Guys, please help with a way to get rid of them. (Regardless of whether these are 'newline characters' or whatever). Because the data will be used for Data Mining purpose. So i rather don't contain any funny characters. Thank you all guys :)))

Comment: @Martin oops, I misread `0a` when in fact it is `a0`. @deceze is right. It's a non-breaking space https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Comment: You can decode the JSON, remove the undesired character(s) from the strings then encode the as JSON again, if needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for everyone in the comment section, who *(at least)* helped me to know those are `non-breaking characters`. I then googled and found a working solution by myself anyhow:

```
$clean_html_body = preg_replace('/\xc2\xa0/', '', $html_body);
```

Thanks again all. :)

Comment: The solution should be that that character set for the JSON at creation time should be properly detected and encoded into UTF-8 or similar. But this raises its own problems of the false positive nature of character encoding detection

Comment: If he does his own json_encoding, he could try adding JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE as an option.

Comment: Yes. But as i mentioned, it was given to me. Means, i wasn't the one generated the JSON file. That also means, i do not own the original data source. So i needed a solution at the point of time i received the JSON files. (The files are too much in amount actually. So i cannot simply manually cleanup)

Answer (score 2):

If you have individual strings that might have non-breaking spaces or line returns at the end of them, you can trim these when putting together your JSON data by using this:

$dat = trim($dat," \t\n\r\0\x0B\xc2\xa0");